# AssertionError in Keras, GAN Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to build a Conditional GAN model based on jacob's code (https://github.com/jacobgil/keras-dcgan). However, the generator_containing_discriminator model throws me an assertion error when the model compiles.

I think it might have something to do with the multiple inputs and ouputs in the generator and discriminator model; keras doesn't like it when I tried to combine the two models.

Basically,  I want the generator to take two inputs: g_inputs and auxiliary_input, and to produce two outputs: T and auxiliary_input. In this case I am simply passing auxiliary_input along.

I want the discriminator to take two inputs: d_inputs and auxiliary_input , and to produce one output: T.

I made sure the sizes are matching, but do you guys know why this still doesn't work when I compile generator_containing_discriminator? Help much appreciated!

My Code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.layers import Reshape, concatenate
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Flatten
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')


#g_inputs is the input for generator
#auxiliary_input is the condition
#d_inputs is the input for discriminator
g_inputs = (Input(shape=(110,), dtype='float32', name='g_inputs'))
auxiliary_input = (Input(shape=(10,), dtype='float32', name='auxiliary_input'))
d_inputs = (Input(shape=(1,28,28), dtype='float32', name='d_inputs'))


def generator_model():
    T = (Dense(1024))(g_inputs)
    T = (Dense(128*7*7))(T)
    T = (BatchNormalization())(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    T = (Reshape((128, 7, 7), input_shape=(128*7*7,)))(T)
    T = (UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))(T)
    T = (Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same'))(T)
    T = (BatchNormalization())(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    T = (UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))(T)
    T = (Convolution2D(1, 5, 5, border_mode='same'))(T)
    T = (BatchNormalization())(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    model = Model(input=[g_inputs, auxiliary_input], output=[T,auxiliary_input])
    return model

def discriminator_model():
    T = (Convolution2D(filters= 64, kernel_size= (5,5), padding='same'))(d_inputs)
    T = (BatchNormalization())(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    T = (MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))(T)
    T = (Convolution2D(128, 5, 5))(T)
    T = (BatchNormalization())(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    T = (MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))(T)
    T = (Flatten())(T)
    T = concatenate([T, auxiliary_input])
    T = (Dense(1024))(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    T = (Dense(1))(T)
    T = (Activation('sigmoid'))(T)
    model = Model(input=[d_inputs,auxiliary_input], output=T)
    return model

def generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator):
    T1 = generator([g_inputs, auxiliary_input])
    discriminator.trainable = False
    T2 = discriminator(T1)
    model = Model(input=[g_inputs, auxiliary_input], output=T2)
    return model



discriminator = discriminator_model()
generator = generator_model()


generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator).summary()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I think the problem is in generator. It simply doesn't use "auxiliary_input". It's the descriminator who does.

Comment: Hi you are right, I fixed it by simply deleting the auxiliary_input from the generator, thanks for answering!